# Where is the mySQL database located in a Wordpress site's directory tree?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

What is the location of the actual files being backed up when a Wordpress mySQL database is backed up or exported?

I want to know if it is possible to do a completely manual backup by just downloading these files via FTP, as opposed to using a plugin, phpMyAdmin, or other tool.

If this can't be done, why?

edit: wordpress.org

If you're downvoting this question, please explain why.  Every site I have seen about backing up a Wordpress installation requires one to download a specific mySQL export.  What is the problem with wondering where that data is before it is exported by a tool like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Please accept my answer or leave a comment if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Wordpress]

I'm assuming that you are using a **Wordpress.com** site then you can either export the database in XML format from the *tools* menu in your dashboard or you need to contact a "Wordpress Happiness Engineer" (Wordpress' tech guys to get them to export it for you).

Comment: wordpress.org .. I know about the content export, I'm talking about the mySQL database that is usually exported via phpMyAdmin, etc.